# Apply a trim on the output generated by filter_complex without a separate command

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-filters

I have a filter complex expression that takes 4 input videos and combines them in 4 corners of the screen synced at a particular start time from each video

```
ffmpeg \
    -i first_vid.mkv \
    -i second_vid.mp4 \
    -i third_vid.mkv \
    -i fourth_vid.mkv  \
    -filter_complex \
        "nullsrc=size=1280x720 [base]; \
        [0:v] \
            trim=start=40,\
            setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,\
            scale=640x360,\
            drawtext=fontfile=/Users/vr/Downloads/gameplay_vids/generated/control-freak-font/CONTF___.ttf\
            :text='one'\
            :fontsize=32\
            :fontcolor=0xFFFFFF\
            :alpha='if(lt(t,30),0,if(lt(t,35),(t-30)/5,if(lt(t,65),1,if(lt(t,70),(5-(t-65))/5,0))))'\
            :x=w-text_w-12\
            :y=h-text_h-12 [upperleft];\
        [1:v] \
            trim=start=35.05, \
            setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, \
            scale=640x360, \
            drawtext=fontfile=/Users/vr/Downloads/gameplay_vids/generated/control-freak-font/CONTF___.ttf \
            :text='two' \
            :fontsize=32 \
            :fontcolor=0xFFFFFF \
            :alpha='if(lt(t,30),0,if(lt(t,35),(t-30)/5,if(lt(t,65),1,if(lt(t,70),(5-(t-65))/5,0))))' \
            :x=w-text_w-12 \
            :y=h-text_h-12 [upperright]; \
        [2:v] \
            trim=start=36.467, \
            setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, \
            scale=640x360, \
            drawtext=fontfile=/Users/vr/Downloads/gameplay_vids/generated/control-freak-font/CONTF___.ttf \
           :text='three' \
           :fontsize=32 \
           :fontcolor=0xFFFFFF \
           :alpha='if(lt(t,30),0,if(lt(t,35),(t-30)/5,if(lt(t,65),1,if(lt(t,70),(5-(t-65))/5,0))))' \
           :x=w-text_w-12 \
           :y=h-text_h-12 [lowerleft]; \
        [3:v] \
            trim=start=35.097, \
            setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, \
            scale=640x360, \
            drawtext=fontfile=/Users/vr/Downloads/gameplay_vids/generated/control-freak-font/CONTF___.ttf \
           :text='four' \
           :fontsize=32 \
           :fontcolor=0xFFFFFF \
           :alpha='if(lt(t,30),0,if(lt(t,35),(t-30)/5,if(lt(t,65),1,if(lt(t,70),(5-(t-65))/5,0))))' \
           :x=w-text_w-12 \
           :y=h-text_h-12 [lowerright];  \
        [2:a] \
           atrim=start=36.467, \
           asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[outa]; \
           [base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1]; \
           [tmp1][upperright] overlay=shortest=1:x=640 \
           [tmp2];[tmp2][lowerleft] overlay=shortest=1:y=360 \
           [tmp3];[tmp3][lowerright] overlay=shortest=1:x=640:y=360[v] \
    " -map "[v]" -map "[outa]" -c:v libx264 -shortest -ss 00:00 -to 9999 "output.mp4"
```

- I want to remove the part between 37:23 and 37:33 of the output video
- Is there a way I can do this without writing a separate ffmpeg command like a pipe or a chain or multiple filter_complex expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For trimming out the specified portion, you'll need to split, trim, and then concat those segments.

```
[2:a] \
   atrim=start=36.467, \
   asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS, asplit=2 [apre][apost]; \
   [apre]atrim=0:2253[apre];[apost]atrim=2263,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[apost]; \
```

and then later on,

```
[tmp3][lowerright] overlay=shortest=1:x=640:y=360,split=2[vpre][vpost]; \
[vpre]trim=0:2253[vpre];[vpost]trim=2263,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vpost]; \
[vpre][apre][vpost][apost]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][outa] \
```

Comment: but i want the video from 00:00 to 37:33 and then 37:43 to end of the clip, i assume you cannot use ss twice

Comment: Ah, you want to trim **out** that portion. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: thank you very much that works!!!